# Lagrangian Floer theory for negative monotone symplectic manifolds and Lagrangians

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, floer-homology

In the paper "Floer cohomology of Lagrangian intersections and pseudo-holomorphic Disks I", Oh shows that for a compact monotone Lagrangian $L$ in a closed monotone symplectic manifold $M$ with minimal Maslov number $3$  one can define a Floer theory and hence the Lagrangian will be non-displaceable.

My question is that the definitions for monotone involve constants $\lambda>0,\alpha>0$, one for the definition of $L$ to be monotone and the other for the definition of $M$ to be monotone. My question is that what happens if we ask that $\lambda<0,\alpha<0$ ?
From what I've seen I would expect that the theory still works as long as the constants have the same sign but I would love to hear some input on this. Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.